# Month calculation in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I am working in neo4j database.

i have csv file column is ENTRY_DATE format is "08-apr-15" String type date.and current date format is "21-10-2016".How to change the String type Entry_date is like current date format.but my need is compare the current date with entry_date column then calculate the difference of month between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse both strings using Cypher's string functions.

```
WITH {current_date} AS current_date
WITH split(current_date, '-') AS month_tuple
WITH month_tuple[1] AS c_month, month_tuple[2] AS c_year
WITH {jan: 1, feb: 2, ... dec: 12} AS month_map, c_month, c_year
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "place" AS row
WITH row, row.ENTRY_DATE as e_date, c_month, c_year, month_map
WITH row, c_month, c_year, split(e_date, '-') AS e_tuple, month_map
WITH row, c_month, c_year, e_tuple[2] AS e_year, e_tuple[1] AS e_month_key, month_map
WITH row, (toInt(e_year) -toInt(c_year)) * 12 as year_diff, month_map[e_month_key] - toInt(c_month) AS month_diff
WITH row, year_diff + month_diff AS months_later
```

But InverseFalcon is definitely right in that this would be way better if handled through the backend. Clean up your CSV before import and pass in a better source of current date and you can cut most of that query out.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j doesn't have much support for date/time operations at all. If your backend framework/language has good date/time support, I'd recommend doing that calculation there instead of from the db itself.

But if you are looking for a pure neo4j solution, the APOC Procedures library has some [conversion and formatting support](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support), but if that's not enough, you may want to look at [GraphAware's neo4j timetree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree). That should give you some graph operations for finding the years or months between different dates.